# How to record a discount to buy into the session? Opencart 2

Tags: php, session, opencart, opencart2.x

On the website there are buttons to receive the discount when the buyer fulfills the conditions, he charged the discount to the purchase. 
How to record the discount in the session, so the total purchase price was already discounted. The online store on Opencart 2.

Answer (score 0):

A global coupon for all visitors?

Create a coupon in admin.

Add the coupon's session to `catalog/controller/startup/session.php`

Example:

```
this->session->data['coupon'] = 'coupon1234';
```

If this coupon expires while the code is still there, it may produce errors at checkout, so you might want to do an extra query to check its expiry date, or give it an expiry of 60 years.

Comment: There's not really a coupon, a discount, for example 3% of your purchase. It needs to be added to the purchase.

Comment: You could create a 'hidden' coupon (that you use solely for this purpose and don't distribute to customers otherwise) that achieves this, opposed to adding standalone code that would achieve the same result.